# Accessing Mercurial repositories over SSH

Tags: mercurial, ssh

I can successfully access repositories over http:// using hgweb.cgi:

```
$ hg clone http://mydomain.com/scgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/myrepo
```

I can also successfully ssh into mydomain.com using a password.

```
$ ssh myname@mydomain.com
myname@mydomain.com's password:  xxxxxx
Last login: Sat Jun 9 .....
myname@mydomain.com [~]# ls public_html/scgi-bin
./ ../ hgweb.cgi*, hgweb.config
```

However I can't deduce how to serve repositories via SSH. For example, this doesn't work:

```
$ hg clone ssh://myname@mydomain.com/public_html/scgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/myrepo
myname@mydomain.com's password: xxxxx
remote: stdin: is not a tty
remote: bash: hg: command not found
abort: no suitable response from remote hg!
```

I'm concluding that unlike http://, ssh:// doesn't know how to run the cgi script, would that be correct? Is there a solution to this?

(btw: this is on shared hosting, where http's root is public_html/, ssh's root is one directory up.)

Comment: If you use the `hg clone --verbose` it will show you something like `running ssh myname@mydomain.com "hg -R ... serve --stdio"` which is a big hint to what isn't working.

Comment: Ok, that revealed quite a bit thanks. I can see the 'hg clone' actually calls hg on the remote server, so I don't need to go through hgweb.cgi. It appears now I just have to work out how to get the right PATH set up for hg in the SSH environment, as hg still isn't being found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTTP is not the same as SSH.  HTTP is a stateless, request-based transmission protocol.  SSH is a protocol which establishes a permanent, stateful connection between two machines.

Your HTTP URL looks like a full path to a repository, but it goes through a web server, which is executing the hgweb.cgi script, passing it myrepo as an argument.  The hgweb.cgi script runs Mercurial on the server against the myrepo repository (it pulls the actual location from a config file on the server). The command chain looks like this:

```
Local Mercurial -> HTTP -> Web Server -> hgweb.cgi > Server Mercurial
```

The SSH URL you're using in the second example tells Mercurial to log into the `mydomain.com` server as `myname`, and it can find the repository at `/public_html/scgi-bin/hgweb.cgi/myrepo`.  Most likely, that isn't where your repo is at.  The command chain looks like this:

```
Local Mercurial -> SSH -> Server file system
```

You need to change your SSH URL to use the absolute path to the repo on the server:

```
hg clone ssh://myname@mydomain.com/path/to/myrepo
```

It also looks like the server can't find the Mercurial executable.

Answer (score 0):

Upon using hg's 'verbose' option, two problems were revealed:

1. When called over ssh, hg automatically tries to run the hg server, hence no need to go via hgweb.cgi.
2. The path for the hg command (which was set in .bash_profile) didn't get used for non-interactive SSH commands. I had to put the path to hg somewhere that was, such as .bashrc.

Fixing all that up, the following command worked as expected:

```
hg clone ssh://myname@mydomain.com/public_html/myrepo
```